# URL Rewrite query database?

Tags: php, mysql, url, url-rewriting, seo

I'm trying to understand how URL rewriting works. I have the following link.

```
mysite.com/profile.php?id=23
```

I want to rewrite the above url with the users first and last name.

```
mysite.com/directory/liam-gallagher
```

From what I've read however you specify the rule for what the url should be output as, but how do I query my table to get each user name?

Sorry if this is hard to understand, I've confused myself!

Comment: You just search for the name instead of the ID. Can you clarify what you are unsure about?

Comment: If I searched for the name instead, what if I had 2 users with the same name?

Comment: @Liam You shouldn't! You'll need to create a unique URL slug for each person!

Comment: @Liam you'll have to prevent that from happening. Or do it like Stack Overflow - look at your profile URL: they use the numeric ID to identify you, but they add your name at the end for SEO and nice-lookingness purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking at this from the wrong direction. You can't do that kind of automatic url rewrite. The best is to create an all over url rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and create a specific name for a user in the db that will be used as an url.

```
+---------+----------+------+-----------+----------------+
| user_id | username | name | surname   | url            |
+---------+----------+------+-----------+----------------+
|      23 | liam     | Liam | Gallagher | liam-gallagher |
+---------+----------+------+-----------+----------------+
```

Now when someone accesses your `http://mysite.com/directory/liam-gallagher`, you can read the last entry and find the `user_id` in you database and make your script do the rest.

The other way is as [Pekka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka) suggested. Create an url like `http://mysite.com/directory/23/liam-gallagher` and read the id from the link. But I personally don't like that kind of urls. They are just fast/lazy workarounds in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Something like (just a draft, adapt to your own needs...):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /$1/$2.php?id=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach I've used works as follows.

Make a rewrite rule, e.g.

```
mysite.com/directory/(.*)
```

That redirects to:

```
mysite.com/profile.php?user=%1
```

Having %1 as the parameter captured from the rule.

Then grab the user from the query parameter on the profile page and fetch the ID for that user from the db.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html