# PHP rewrite rule as database values

Tags: php, database, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite 
`www.example.com/folder/35467/title.html` onto

```
www.example.com/folder/?id=35467
```

`id` and `title` comes from the database. I'm gona put the htaccess file into the "folder".

Comment: so what's the actual question here? have you tried anyhing? google search on URL rewriting?

Comment: I allready use rewriting but not as values from database

Comment: But you still did not provide an actual question. What do you want to achieve

Comment: I need to replace ?id= with the p or anything and add the title value from the database where title is associated to the questioned id

Comment: Links are links.. you can manipulate them with htaccess.. DB don't have anything to do with it..

Comment: It does, this is an example: http://www.stylefruits.de/partyoutfit-puenktchen-auf-schwarz/o2755210. "partyoutfit-puenktchen-auf-schwarz" comes from the database and is associated with the id 2755210

Comment: And if you try to change anything in "partyoutfit-puenktchen-auf-schwarz" it will be written back, so dublicate content will be prevent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the htaccess file is going to be in `/folder/` then you need these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)\.html ?id=$1 [L]
```

To redirect access with the id query string, you can check the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable in your `index.php`.

```
if ( !strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'.html') ) {
    // The request that was made wasn't with the nicer looking URL
    header("Location: /folder/$id/$title.html");
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your script root folder
## path relative to web root

    RewriteBase /

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

index.php

```
list (,,$id,$title) = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$link = 'www.example.com/folder/?id='. $id;
```

Comment: I'll try it and mark if it works. Otherwise I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972608/url-rewrite-query-database

Comment: this works on the assumption that you are running Apache2 web server with MOD_REWRITE module enabled.